# SQLite database gets overwritten when manually placed onto device

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

I have been trying to write a lite program version for android that also syncs with a microsoft access datatbase. I first developed the database in access because it was easier and now i want to migrate and synchronize to android with a SQLite backup/synced file.

When i simply replace the SQLite file on an emulated device through the Device Explorer it works fine. When i try to replace the SQLite file on a physical device through the Device Explorer it doesn't work. Every time it replaces the file with a new version and relegates the old database with a .corrupt extension.

I am new to Android Studio and am using Kotlin. I see a lot of answers for Android Studio are in Java which might confuse me. My eventual plan is to synchronize the databases to an SQLite database cloud file and keep a synchronized copy on each device. So the basic problem is between the emulated device and the physical device.

My development environment is Ubuntu. My system is too slow to run in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

One cause may be that you are replacing one file but not another 2 files.

With later versions of Android (9+ [see](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/compatibility-wal)), the default mode changed from journal mode to WAL (Write-Ahead Logging).

In journal mode the journal keeps a record of changes applied to the database, so it is not important as far as the actual database file is concerned.

In WAL mode changes are written to the wal file (database file name suffixed with -wal and -shm (a wal file for the wal file)). If you replace the database file but leave the -wal file and the -wal file is not empty then sqlite will see that the -wal file is not the one for the database file (it belongs to the now overwritten/replaced database) and thus will consider that the database is corrupt, as per :-

> If a database file is separated from its WAL file, then transactions that were previously committed to the database might be lost, or the database file might become corrupted. https://sqlite.org/wal.html#the_wal_file

The fix, if this is the issue, would be to delete the -wal file and the -shm file as well as overwriting/replacing the actual database file.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. My phone uses the -journal file. When i delete the SQLite db file and the db-journal file and replace it with the populated database i still get the same result. My phone is running Android 9. Not sure if it's an android version issue. The Emulator is running Android 11.

Comment: It appears that the phone only 'likes' the SQLite db that it creates itself. It cannot be overwritten?

Comment: Solved the issue by creating a blank db on the device. copying it and populating it through sql statements and then transfering it back onto the device. It is possible the schemas did not match 100%